# Coding Isomap (& MDS) function using only numpy and scipy in python

Tags: python, numpy, dimensionality-reduction, epsilon, mds

I have coded Isomap function starting with computing the eulidean distance matrix (using scipy.spatial.distance.cdist), next basing on K-nearest neighbors method and Dijkstra algorithm (to determinate the shortest path) I have Computed the full distance matrix over all paths, finally I have did map computations, following by the dimensionality reduction.
BUT, I want to use epsilon instead of K-nearest neighbors like in the following :

Y = isomap (X, epsilon, d)

• X is an n × m matrix which corresponds to n points with m attributes.

• epsilon is an anonymous function of the distance matrix used to find the parameters of neighborhood. (The neighborhood graph must be formed by eliminating the edges whose width is greater to epsilon of the complete distance graph).

• d is a parameter which signifies the output dimension.

• Y is an n × d matrix, which signifies the embedding resulting from isomap.

THANKS in advance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


def distance_Matrix(X):
    return cdist(X,X,'euclidean')

def Dijkstra(h):
    q = h.copy()
    for i in range(ndata):
        for j in range(ndata):
            k = np.argmin(q[i,:])
            while not(np.isinf(q[i,k])):
                q[i,k] = np.inf
                for l in neighbours[k,:]:
                    possible = h[i,l] + h[l,k]
                    if possible < h[i,k]:
                        h[i,k] = possible
                k = np.argmin(q[i,:])
    return h

def MDS(D,newdim=2):  

    n = D.shape[0]
    # Torgerson formula
    I = np.eye(n)
    J = np.ones(D.shape)
    J = I-(1/n)*J
    B = (-1/2)*np.dot(np.dot(J,D),np.dot(D,J))  # B = -(1/2).JD²J

    # 
    eigenval, eigenvec = np.linalg.eig(B)
    indices = np.argsort(eigenval)[::-1]   
    eigenval = eigenval[indices]
    eigenvec = eigenvec[:, indices]

    # dimension reduction
    K = eigenvec[:, :newdim]
    L = np.diag(eigenval[:newdim])  
    # result
    Y = K @ L **(1/2)    
    return np.real(Y)

def isomap(data,newdim=2,K=12):

    ndata = np.shape(data)[0]
    ndim = np.shape(data)[1]

    d = distance_Matrix(X)

    # replace begin 
    # K-nearest neighbours
    indices = d.argsort()
    #notneighbours = indices[:,K+1:]
    neighbours = indices[:,:K+1]
    # replace end

    h = np.ones((ndata,ndata),dtype=float)*np.inf
    for i in range(ndata):
        h[i,neighbours[i,:]] = d[i,neighbours[i,:]]
    h = Dijkstra(h)
    return MDS(h,newdim)
```

Comment: Please try to formulate this question by giving ample code to help potential takers.

Comment: @koshygeorge what about now ?

Comment: Lots of improvement. I have added the comments "replace begin" and "replace end" in the function `isomap` where I think is the location you need help. Please re-edit if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, I want to determinate the neighbours with "the radius epsilon " instead of fixing the number of neighbours (k).

Answer (score 0):

Try [`sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph.html) for your distance matrix

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).